# check if jquery ui accordion exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

is there an easy way to tell if a jquery accordion exists on the page...i am trying to dynamically build accordion based on selection that runs through $ajax, reads values from xml, and depending on the xml file selected builds strings the make up the accordion, and finally appends it.

I think that if the accordion already exists on the page, and the user selects another file, I am having trouble destroying the accordion, clearing the html, append the new string, then creating a new accordion...

like

```
$("#accordion").accordion('destory').html('').append(string).accordion();
```

seems like if there is not already an accordion this idea breaks....thinking maybe i can just check?? thanks for any help to beginner!

Comment: This looks fine, as long as you are running it every time new content is available and the accordion's element exists on the page when the code runs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect that you could try checking `.data()`.

```
var isAccordion = !!$("#accordion").data("ui-accordion");
```

Or, by checking the `ui-accordion` classname using `.hasClass()` which is added upon initialization.

```
var isAccordion = $("#accordion").hasClass("ui-accordion");
```

Comment: or by specific ui-accordion css classes if they are exists

Comment: I added it for the sake of completeness

Comment: to me idea of checking class is to check for `length` of class in case selector for accordion is unknown, could then locate accordion without knowing it's ID

Comment: @Alexander ..worked. it actually worked with the first method given, but I tried both out of curiosity and they both did the trick! Just separated out .accordion('destroy') from the above (OP) line, and added to if with your example. thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You could try with .length

[Count the element using .length](http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/EJJZt/)

Or something like this

```
if($('#accordion').length > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Checking the length doesn't seem to be correct here, the jQuery object could exist but the ui-accordion might not be there